# How can I change google chrome preferences programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to be able to change Chrome's preferences programmatically, particularly the path that files download to. I can access Chrome's 'Preferences' file (located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`) and change the download directory. If Chrome is not running, then these changes will take hold and everything works fine.

If the browser is running, however, any changes I make to the Preferences file are overwritten once I do anything in the browser. Is there any way to change this? How do I change the preferences and have it take hold immediately and not be overwritten? I am running Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain this behaviour can't be overridden, but I suspect it's by design. If so, one method for programatically achieving what you want is to kill the process before making any changes. From a batch file, this is as straight forward as

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
```

Running this before making your changes should make sure all instances of Chrome as closed before hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping this could be done without having to shut down chrome.